# how will i change the color of a font based on a value using angularjs directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create a directive that can change the font color of the text displayed on a span based on some value that is not displayed.
 I have an array:

```
 $scope.due =[{somedate: "April.8.2010"}, {past:"yes"}];
```

If the value of "past " is yes, then the value inside the span: `<span>{{somedue.date}}</span>` will be color red, else if "past" is no, then font color is black. I am new with angularjs so i would appreciate it if you can suggest on how can i do this using angularjs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ng-class`

```
<span ng-class="{red: past == 'yes', black: past == 'no'}">{{somedue.date}}</span>
```

where the classes red or black will be applied.  You can style those via CSS to make the color red / black.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/NHS73/

Your data structure was odd in your example, it has been modified in mine to showcase `ng-class`.

Also: You could use `true` / `false` and not need to do a string comparison to `'yes'`/`'no'`.

Comment: This works and it is a very good example. Now I understand how to use ng-class. Thanks