# How to change the color of each instance of a word in an html table with css?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the following table in html using AngularJS:

```
<table id="searchTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Observation</th>
            <th>Reported By</th>
            <th>Verified By</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="observation in observations| filter:searchText">
            <th> {{$index + 1}} </th>
            <th>{{observation.clinicalType}}</th>
            <th>{{observation.reportedBy}}</th>
            <th>{{observation.verifiedBy}}</th>
            <th>{{observation.reportedDate}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the columns "Observations", "Reported By", "Verified By", and "Date", it is possible to have the string "NULL". I was wondering if there is a quick and easy way in CSS to color each instance of "NULL" in red in all of the four columns? I've been stuck there for quite some time.

Comment: I think the better is doing it by jQuery or JS.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I finally found a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745001/how-will-i-change-the-color-of-a-font-based-on-a-value-using-angularjs-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd suggest doing this in Jquery. You could look for all `<th>` elements that contain "NULL" and change them to red by doing the following...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("th:contains('NULL')").css("color", "red");

});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/97oqnuyx/

**EDIT:** Because you've graciously accepted my answer, however it actually doesn't seem to solve the issue in your specific case, I feel I should make sure that I'm not spreading misinformation in the event people find this.

While my answer above will work in many cases, this is probably not the way to go if you're using Angular. In that event, you're looking for a solution more like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745001/how-will-i-change-the-color-of-a-font-based-on-a-value-using-angularjs-directive), which OP linked to in a comment above.

Comment: Hi! I tried this, but it's not working. "NULL" appears when I use data-ng-repeat from Angular. Hence, "NULL" is not already loaded in the DOM when the document loads, no? Or perhaps I am making a big mistake. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hm, quite honestly I'm not proficient in Angular but I understand the concern. Just to confirm, there aren't any console errors, correct? Try changing `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load`, or perhaps there's some sort of Angular callback to capture a "data load" event? Sorry!

Comment: Using Angular and you suggest JQuery? Why? Angular offers ng-style for just this.

Comment: @Darren I hadn't realized that it wouldn't work, however if you've noticed, I went back and edited my answer with a proper solution using Angular as well. Chill.